# Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: sql-server, laravel, varbinarymax

I'm using MySQL in development, storing base64 image in `longblob` data type.

But I'm getting error below when trying to insert data after I changed database to MS SQL & data type to `varbinary(max)`

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

So I put a mutator to get this around as below,

```
public function setItemPictureAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['item_picture'] = DB::raw('CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), "'. $value .'")');
}
```

but I'm getting error below when trying to store the base64 image;

> The identifier that starts with '/9j/4QxnRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAAYgEbAAUAAAABAAAAagEoAAMAAAABAAMAAAExAAIAAAAeAAAAcgEyAAIAAAAUAAAAkIdp' is too long. Maximum length is 128`

What did I miss?

EDIT: Somehow I got this work after I changed to `$this->attributes['item_picture'] = DB::raw("CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '". $value ."')");`; notice that I switched the double quote with single quote and vice versa in `DB::raw`. Maybe someone can explain why

Comment: Somehow I get this work after I changed to `$this->attributes['item_picture'] = DB::raw("CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '". $value ."')");`; notice that I switched the double quote with single quote and vice versa in `DB::raw`.

Comment: It might be a good idea to post an answer to your own question and mark that as the best answer, to remove it from the unanswered queue :)

Comment: @sulaimansudirman I am faced with the same issue using a stored procedure.  Could you possibly show me how you ended up writing your query to overcome this issue.  I thought stored procedures in Laravel don't go through a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I got this work after I changed to

```
$this->attributes['item_picture'] = DB::raw("CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '". $value ."')");;
```

notice that I switched the double quote with single quote and vice versa in `DB::raw`. Maybe someone can explain why

Comment: Because single quotes are for strings in SQL